# Failed to solve with frontend Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am pretty new to Docker and am trying to build a Docker image with plain HTML, but I have this error message, saying

> failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount602954594/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

My folder directory is like this:

```
C:\Users\hailey\Desktop\GitTest
                               |- Dockerfile.txt
                               |- README.md
                               |- testHelloWorld.html
```

Inside of the Dockerfile, I have

```
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR C/Users/hailey/Desktop/GitTest
COPY testHelloWorld.html .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["html","testHelloWorld.html"]
```

I did my command `docker build .` inside of the directory *C:\Users\hailey\Desktop\GitTest* and then got:

```
[+] Building 0.1s (2/2) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B
 => [internal] load .dockerignore
 => => transferring context: 2B
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount602954594/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 303, accepted):

The name of Docker files doesn't have any extension. It's just `Dockerfile` with capital `D` and lowercase `f`.

You can also specify the Dockerfile name, such as `docker build . -f Dockerfile.txt` if you'd like to name it something else.

Comment: I got this error even with the correct filename. What saved me was adding the -f Dockerfile, e.g., docker build -t tagname . -f Dockerfile

Comment: In my testing, either `dockerfile` or `Dockerfile` with no extension work; anything else needs to be specified with the `-f` flag as in the below answer.

Comment: thank you! I just got started with Docker and I inadvertently named my file `DockerFile` and started getting the error reported by OP. After changing it to `Dockerfile` as per your enlightening comment, everything started working :)

Comment: if use `docker-compose` set dockerfile: to`Dockerfile` in `docker-compose.yaml` file

Comment: Just as a reminder, check if you are in the project root directory

Comment: Thanks, removing the extension worked. I was using Visual Studio Code and they automatically gave my file the `.dockerfile` extension when I saved it.

Comment: Thanks, I had named the docker file as DockerFile, so changing the name to Dockerfile worked perfectly.

Comment: I fell for exactly the same reason what @BaranYeni wrote. Not being in the project root directoy.

Comment: I renamed my DockerFile to Dockerfile and it worked

Answer (score 35):

One can provide the filename of the Docker file using `-f`.

For instance, if your Docker file is called `Dockerfile.base`, call the `build` command as follows:

```
docker build . -f Dockerfile.base -t helloworld
```

Then, you can start the build image using the following command:

```
docker run --rm -it helloworld
```

Comment: ...Well I feel dumb. This isn't my first rodeo with docker, I should've been able to interpret that error. Thanks!

Comment: It works because unless you have `dockerfile` or `Dockerfile` as the exact filename (without an extension) you need to specify to docker which file you want to use to build the container when using the `docker build` command. Also important to note you must be in the same directory as you're running the command from for it to work (why I found myself on this question in the first place).

Answer (score 28):

I would like to sum up the information from different answers in one answer, and also add my own experience that brought me to this question:

1. Ensure that you're in the same directory that contains your dockerfile as where you're running your command from (running `ls` or `dir` depending on if you're using Linux or Windows/cmd shell respectively to determine if the file you'll use to build your docker container exists there)
2. Docker will accept at least two (maybe only two?) default names for dockerfiles: `dockerfile` and `Dockerfile`. If you have other capitals in the filename it will most likely fail. Also note that the default filenames have no file extension (so if you're to create the file in Notepad for instance, it may be a .txt or another extension by default). There is another answer here that shows how to save it without a filename from notepad, but you can also use the following commands in Linux and Windows command prompt, respectively:
   `mv dockerfile.txt dockerfile`
   `ren dockerfile.txt dockerfile`
3. If you need to use a different name instead of the default `dockerfile`/`Dockerfile`, then you can use the option `-f` ([link to docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options)), which states:

> -f, --file string             Name of the Dockerfile (Default is 'PATH/Dockerfile')

Taken from another answer, here's an example of how you can use that command:

```
  docker build . -f Dockerfile.base -t helloworld
```

And just to bring it all together, you don't need to use the filename again once the container is built, so you can just run it with:

```
docker run --rm -it helloworld
```

Comment: My Dockerfile was on another directory. Moved to same directory and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

If you don't really need to use buildkit:

Try to set those .envs before executing your build/Docker composer:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
export COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=0
```

Answer (score 16):

Sorry for hearing that you've an issue. Are you sure about **naming your file -> "Dockerfile" ? it shouldn't be "dockerfile" nor "DockerFile"**

Answer (score 9):

The issue in my case was, the file name was correct, but the extension was `txt`.

I opened [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) and pasted the `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1` line and after that saved that file from Notepad++ like below.

[image]

Once the file is saved, it will look like below:

[image]

Comment: kudos for handdrawn highlighting!

Answer (score 8):

For those who use `docker-compose build` also make sure you have properly set `build` path in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: ./services/web/ --> this folder should contain your Dockerfile, otherwise you will have the above error
```

Comment: I had 2 dots (`..`) at `build` instead of one and almost went nuts as none of the other solutions worked... :)

Answer (score 5):

I just had this same issue, and it turned out I had to place the Docker file in the right folder—the root project folder.

Answer (score 4):

1: Make sure docker file is named "Dockerfile" without any extension.

2: Make sure you are running the command from the location where your Dockerfile is kept.

Answer (score 3):

For me, I just go the root path of project where the Docker file exists.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned before... the issue for me was the Dockerfile name. I had "DockerFile" by accident.

Changing the name to Dockerfile with the lowercase f and rerunning the build command fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

Rename your **Dockerfile.txt** to just as this **Dockerfile**. Because the dockerfile has no extensions.

Comment: That is a repeat of previous answers.

Answer (score 3):

Just be in the same folder where your Dockerfile is located at and run the build command that is how I solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error: It could be anything. Mine wasn't anything specific... I had incorrectly named and referenced one of the files in the configurations, so when trying to run build it could not find that file.

It had nothing to do with `frontend dockerfile.v0` (totally different file). Check all your file are named and referenced correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Check the name of Dockerfile. It should be "Dockerfile".

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by giving it the full file extension to my Dockerfile

```
docker build -t testapi . -f [YOUR_FILE_EXTENSION]/Dockerfile
```

when you give your file extension don't give the relative one give the whole extension such as `D:/projects/asp6.0/publish/Dockerfile`

Comment: Yes It works with full ABSOLUTE path to Dockerfile

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, the error was "no space left on device".

I executed the command: `docker system prune` and it fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Most answers talk about the correct way to name the Dockerfile but this problem is caused when the `docker build -t vicohq/nodeapp .` command is ran outside the development environment. If you use cmd or shell instead of the terminal in the IDE with your Dockerfile, the command won't access your Dockerfile hence the error.

Comment: Hi, so would would be the solution? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue while building a [Visual Studio 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2019) generated Docker file:

> failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount037306220/dockerfile: no such file or directory

Essentially, the Docker file is being referred from within the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) (WSL). The tool mounted my local file system and was accessing the Docker file in the context of WSL.
As file names are case sensitive on Linux, the Docker command faithfully reported the error:

**>> dockerfile: no such file or directory**

Renaming the **Dockerfile** to "**dockerfile**" resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue running "docker build -t getting-started ." from the [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) terminal.

But when I've executed the same command in [CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) (Windows 10) it worked with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from correcting the Dockerfile name, that error can also happen if you add an extra dot at the end

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31684307)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, i solved
My case was: in docker-compose.yml i had build->dockerfile: DockerFile
while my Dockerfile was f (lowercase)

Comment: Hi, while your answer seems to address the question, it's substantially a duplicate of the accepted one. While answering, be sure to add some valuable information. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the correct directory first, and docker desktop is running.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue working with a React app. I had to move the Dockerfile from src to the project root folder and restarted Docker desktop—it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you see the list using "ls" or "dir" command.

In my case I create Dockerfile using Mac's Textedit and it had a hidden .rtf extension.

After removing the extension it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Another issue I had with this error was around the location in which I was executing the command.
It might be useful for some to run the command from the correct directory (where the Dockerfile resides) and include the appropriate naming convention when creating the docker file. Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was wrong directory specification of Dockerfile location. I initially specified parent directory (instead of the subdirectory where actually the Dockerfile was residing) in docker-compose.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

you can try at this

```
docker build -t testdemo:1.0 .\Dockerfile.txt
```

works for me on windows

Comment: (I find this surprising since the last argument is a _directory_ containing the build context.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are using Docker Compose with fragments, you cannot partially override the `build` key. For instance:

```yaml
  prep: &node
    build:
      context: './docker'
      dockerfile: 'Dockerfile.pnpm'
      target: 'dev'

  home:
    <<: *node
    build:
      target: 'home'
```

Here, `home` will not have the custom Dockerfile extension.