# Failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount1736287518/Dockerfile-app:

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a Docker Compose project involving MySQL, Angular and Springboot. This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
 nginx:
  container_name: nginx
  image: nginx:1.13
  restart: always
  ports:
   - 80:80
   - 443:443
  volumes:
   - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
 angular:
  container_name: angular
  build: ./angular
  restart: always
  depends_on:
   - angular
  ports:
   - 4200:4200
 mysql:
   container_name: mysql
   image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
   environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: test
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: formation123
    MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
   ports:
    - 3306:3306
   restart: always
 springboot:
   restart: always
   build:
    context: ./springboot
    dockerfile: Dockerfile-app
   working_dir: /springboot
   volumes:
    - ./springboot:/springboot
    - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
   expose:
    - "8080"
   depends_on:
   - nginx
   - mysql
   command: mvn clean spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=docker
```

But when i launch this is the error that i get.

```
[+] Building 0.1s (4/4) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                           
 => [projecto-springboot internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-app                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [projecto-springboot internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CANCELED [projecto-angular internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CANCELED [projecto-angular internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                           0.0s
failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount1901519857/Dockerfile-app: no such file or directory
```

I'm a bit new so i don't know what is causing. I'm launching the Docker Compose in a directory that has 2 subdirectorys with the Angular and Spring Boot Dockerfiles.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** this was a duplicate, with answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76013035/14681457)

This error means that docker cannot find the *docker build file* (commonly called `dockerfile`, but read on) when building a container.

your docker compose has these lines:

```yaml
 springboot:
   restart: always
   build: # from here you are building something
    context: ./springboot
    dockerfile: Dockerfile-app # the name of the dockerfile
```

which means that it will try to build springboot from the file `Dockerfile-app` with context from `./springboot` directory.

make sure to double-check if you have this file (`Dockerfile-app`) in the context directory (`./springboot`).

Error description: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67521172/14681457)

Context/dockerfile explanation: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75418729/14681457)