# Docker compose fails with "failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount[...]/Dockerfile: no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

On Windows 11, with this rather simple `docker-compose.yaml` file

```yaml
version: '3.0'
services:
  php-apache-environment:
    container_name: php-apache
    build: ./php
    volumes:
      - ./php/src:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 8000:80

  db:
    image: mysql:5.6.27
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: PassWord
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 9yI2G0s-sZf37SS5Ml1Kj
    ports:
      - "9906:3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_PORT: 9906
      PMA_USER: test
      PMZ_PASSWORD: 9yI2G0s-sZf37SS5Ml1Kj
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    depends_on:
      - db
```

And the command `docker compose up --detach` the images are cloned but I get the following error:

> failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount1583816350/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

In Docker desktop I see the images but as unused.

I googled this error and came up with [this](https://ayeshalshukri.co.uk/category/guides/docker-error-failed-to-solve-with-frontend-dockerfile/) but the  line `dockerfile: Dockerfile` is rejected with:

> services.phpmyadmin Additional property dockerfile is not allowed

Comment: phpmyadmin does have have an image, so it should not try to find a _Dockerfile_ related to it, so this is not the service causing you an issue. The `php-apache-environment` service, on the other hand does have a `build` instruction, and so, your `./php` folder is probably missing the proper Dockerfile.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε ok.thanks! So what do I change to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can definitely reproduce this having a an empty *php* folder, so missing the *Dockerfile*, with the following minimal example.

File hierarchy:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── php
##  ^-- mind this is an empty folder, not a file
```

And the minimal *docker-compose.yml*:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  php-apache-environment:
    container_name: php-apache
    build: ./php
```

Running `docker compose up` yields the same error as yours:

> failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2757070869/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

So, if you create a *Dockerfile* in the *php* folder, e.g.:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── php
    └── Dockerfile
```

With a content like

```
FROM php:fpm
```

Then the service starts working:

```bash
$ docker compose up    
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container php-apache  Created                               0.1s
Attaching to php-apache
php-apache  | [14-Apr-2023 08:42:10] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
php-apache  | [14-Apr-2023 08:42:10] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

---

And if your file describing the image inside the folder *php* has a different name than the standard one, which is *Dockerfile*, then you have to adapt your *docker-compose.yml*, using the object form of the `build` parameter:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  php-apache-environment:
    container_name: php-apache
    build: 
      context: ./php
      dockerfile: Dockefile.dev # for example
```

<sup>*Related documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#build-definition*</sup>